# python 3.7.4 pip install - NameError: name 'reload' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, pip, reload, nameerror

I'm trying to install django-rules by using

```
python -m pip install django-rules
```

but I get the NameError mentioned in the title. I've read of 'reload' having to be imported for python3 but I don't know how to do that when using the terminal for pip install.

Any ideas of how to install django-rules?

Comment: Please provide the verbose traceback log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see: https://pypi.org/project/django-rules/

Version 0.2 last released at Jun 7, 2011.

Seems to be abandoned Python2-only project. Forget about it or fork it and update to Python 3 yourself.

Comment: Well, forgot to pay attention to the release date. I'm trying to run an existing project from work. Obviously I'm missing something. Thanks!